# Pyspark kernel doesnt start on Jupyterhub

Tags: pyspark, jupyterhub

The Jupyterhub Pyspark kernel used to work very well but now will not start or will have Kernel connected status (doesnt go to idle) but will not run any code in cells. It is using localprocess spawner with PAM auth on Centos.In the jupyterhub logs we see these messages:

```
[I 2020-03-10 15:13:08.644 SingleUserNotebookApp restarter:110] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5), new random ports
Assertion failed: rc == 0 (src/socket_poller.cpp:41)
[W 2020-03-10 15:13:11.666 SingleUserNotebookApp restarter:100] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 2020-03-10 15:13:11.666 SingleUserNotebookApp kernelmanager:127] Kernel 0148c77d-143a-4721-90e7-0d9a41a878c4 died, removing from map.
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by reinstalling sparkmagic in the base conda environment:

`(base) [root@]# pip install sparkmagic`